# How to dynamic cast/ensure typesafety from collection with varying generics

Tags: java, generics

I've decided to use generics in my design, which works fine. Only when I get to abstraction, I got stuck. I'm collecting different instances implementing the same interface with a different generics. To save those in a list, I need to use wildcards, as far as I know. So my current code is like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
    private List<IView<?>> views = new ArrayList<IView<?>>();


    public void addView(IView<?> view)
    {
        this.views.add(view);
    }

    public void handle()
    {
        for (IView<?> view : this.views)
        {       
            // ## ERROR ##
            view.render(
                    view.cast(new Object())
                );
        }
    }
}

public interface IView<T> { 
    public T cast(Object entity);
    public void render(T entity);
}

public class FirstView implements IView<One> {  
    // .. Added to Main-collection views
}

public class SecondView implements IView<Two> { 
    // .. Added to Main-collection views
}
```

I also tried an alternative approach returning a Class from the IView which I then use to call the class.cast. Same problem.

This is NOT accepted by the compiler
- The method Render(Capture#2-of ?) in the type IView(Capture#2-of ?) is not applicable for the arguments (Capture#3-of ?).

I partially think to understand the problem, but I see no way of solving it. It would be very much appriciated if someone could help me getting going again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can assign a value to an `?` "typed" variable. An unbounded "?" means "the original type of the variable is unknown", which means there is no known type it's safe to assign to it. It doesn't mean that the actual value of the type parameter is retrieved at runtime.

The entire idea of using a generic method to do a cast doesn't make sense in Java generics. The only way to do a cast of an unknown type object in a type-safe way is with an actual cast.

The only solution is to get rid of the cast() method, and use raw types:

```
public void handle()
{
    for (IView view : this.views)
    {
        view.render(new Object());
    }
}
```

Assuming the cast() method is only doing casting and not type conversion. If the implementing method that ends up being called is FirstView.render(One object), I believe Java will actually cast the parameter to One. (This can also cause amusing bugs where a ClassCastException is thrown on a line of code with no casts.)

If `cast()` can do a type conversion (in which case, "cast" is a bad name for the operation), that means that every IView *must* be able to accept Object, in which case it doesn't make much sense have the parameter of `render()` be the generic type to begin with. The design I would use is something like the following:

```
interface IView<T> {
    void renderObject(Object o);
    void render(T);
    T coerce(Object o);
}

abstract class ViewBase<T> implements IView<T> {
    void renderObject(Object o) {
        render(coerce(o));
    }
}

class FirstView extends ViewBase<One> {
    // …
}
```

encapsulating the "cast" operation.

There is no statically typesafe way to work with a collection of objects of different types - in Java, `IView<One>` and `IView<Two>` are types as different as `String` and `Integer` and there are no safe conversions between the two.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should reconsider being such a big fan of raw types (you suggested them here and in several comments)? Reading some literature about generics from Angelika Langer or Josh Bloch might help.

Comment: I'd be more willing to swallow your appeal to authority / convention if you backed it up with **typesafe** code solving the OP's issue. I submit that there is no typesafe way to declare a `List<IView<Whatever>> views`, that will let you store both an IView<One>, and an IView<Two>, and then be able to implement handle() as in the OP. My second proposed solution, the one that introduces `renderObject()`, on the other hand, will let you declare  `fields` as `List<? extends IView<?>>` because it gets rid of the call to a method with a wildcard parameter.

Comment: My first solution uses raw types because they get the job done with a minimum of effort. Assuming that's actually what Josh Bloch means with item 23, I reserve the right to disagree with him and you that it's absolutely verboten to use any raw types anywhere period; I feel they're a good fit to communicate the idea that "I feel like getting the job done instead of spending the afternoon trying to figure out how to make *three lines of code that's correct anyway* adhere to every convention and recommendation out there"

Comment: I like your second proposed solution and agree that there is no typesafe solution for what Robert wants to do. I just do not understand why you suggest using raw types: they hide the issue and are not better than using List<IView<Object>>, which makes the issue explicit, is not more complex, and does not suggest you are dealing with legacy code (which is the convention for using raw types).

Comment: If you declare `fields` as `List<IView<Object>>`, you'd have to do one of the following: 1. Change the signature of `addView()` to `IView<Object>` - this makes no sense because it is, in fact, correct to add any subtype of `IView`. 2. Add an invalid cast from `IView<?>` to `IView<Object>` in `addView()`. 3. The worst of both, change the signature and expect the API clients to do the invalid cast themselves. Alternately, you could cast `fields` to `List<View<Object>>` in `handle()` alone, but the issue the method has should be made explicit with a comment, not implied with bizarre invalid casts

Comment: Essentially, it is my preference to: make the type signatures *in the API* be as complete and correct as possible – this is where I'd try to avoid raw types; avoid doing invalid casts or making API clients do invalid casts, because they're misleading, and don't behave as casts are expected to – which is throw a CCE on the line of the cast. What remains is how to point out "this is a hack to work around a code smell"; I'd use a raw type, you'd use an invalid cast which would issue a compiler warning, which seems like a bikeshed issue to me – the only truly explicit way is to write a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was wondering about the two captures in code `view.render(view.cast(new Object());`, 
I read the appropriate section in [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ602). It states that:

> We cannot call methods through an unbounded wildcard parameterized
>   type that take arguments of the "unknown" type.

PERIOD.

So using a wildcard declaration prevents the use of parameterized arguments, even if type inference were simple, as in your case :( Hence `view.cast(new Object();` is allowed, but `view.render(view.cast(new Object());` isn't.

---

Just for clarification via an example, Angelika gives the following:

```
Box<?> box = new Box<String>("abc");

box.contains("abc");    // error
```

where `contains` takes as argument the parameterized type of Box. She states:

> The invocation is illegal if performed through a reference variable of
>   type `Box<?>` . [Defining the contains method as taking an argument of
>   type Object , instead of T , would avoid this effect.  In this case
>   the contains method would not take an object of "unknown", but an
>   object of "any" type, and it would be permitted to invoke it through a
>   reference variable of type `Box<?>` .]

So she suggests retrieting back to `Object` (similarly to the suggestion in my other answer). Btw, she discourages using raw types, as does Josh Bloch in [Effective Java's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) item 23, "Don’t use raw types in new code".

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the compiler error, i.e. why `view.render(view.cast(new Object());` produces two captures. (I've tried this code with `view` being final, and the same error message shows).

But since `IView<One>` and `IView<Two>` only have `Object` as common type, the way of solving it is using `List<IView<Object>>`.

Comment: `IView<Object>` is *not* a supertype of `IView<One>` or `IView<Two>`.

Comment: To clarify: `List<IView<Object>>` means that **every** item of the list will accept **any** instance of `Object` or a subclass – that is, any object at all as the argument to `render()`. Obviously an `IView<One>` will not accept an Object instance in its `render()` method. `IView<One>` and `IView<Two>` are subclasses of `IView<? extends Object>`, but that's an even less useful signature. The `render()` method of an `IView<? extends Object>` accepts some unknown type that is a descendant of Object – that is, one specific descendant, not any type.

Comment: @Sii: The capture of List<IView<?>> won't be much better than List<IView<Object>> (if One and Two are not closely related in the type hierarchy). List<IView<Object>> is preferred to the raw type, which completely removes any feature generics offer. Things would be different if you knew more about the IView instances, e.g. by declaring IView<T extends IRenderer>...

Comment: But in this case, using List<IView<Object>> is not more typesafe than the raw type – which is the primary feature generics offer. Java will warn you if you try and add an IView<One> to it, and rightly so – it's a bug, because it lets you then assign the retrieve the IView<One> to a variable of type IView<Object>, and if you then call render(new Object()) on this variable, you'll get a ClassCastException despite the fact the line is statically "safe". Using raw types does not make untrue claims about what code is or is not typesafe here.

Comment: And if /every/ IView implementation to be able to render an `Object` (or gracefully fail to do so), then that's what the signature of `render()` should say to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of replaced the casting by returning a typed object (and I slightly changed the example by replacing the new Object with IEntity);

```
public class Main {
    public static List<IView<? extends IEntity<?>>> views = new ArrayList<IView<? extends IEntity<?>>>();

    public static <T extends IEntity<T>> void register(IView<T> view)
    {
        Main.views.add(view);
    }


    public static void handle()
    {
        for (IView<? extends IEntity<?>> view : Main.views)
        {
        // ## Error ##
        /* Bound mismatch: The generic method view(IView<T>) of the type Main 
         * is not applicable for the arguments (IView<capture#1-of ? extends IEntity<?>>). 
         * The inferred type capture#1-of ? extends IEntity<?> is not a valid 
         * substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends IEntity<T>> 
         */             
            Main.view(view);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends IEntity<T>> void view(IView<T> view)
    {
        IKey<T> key = view.getKey(/* Some arg */);
        T entity = key.getEntity();

        view.render(entity);
    }

}

public interface IView<T> {
    public IKey<T> getKey(/* Some args */);
    public void render(T entity);
}

public interface IKey<T> {
    public T getEntity();
}
```

The wildcard is someway bounded, but then it creates another problem (which may actually be the same): Is there a way to check that two wildcards match, i.e.:

```
for (IView<? extends IEntity<?>> view : Main.views)
```

Where ? can only be one (=the same) (generic)type?

Comment: Try declaring the loop variable as: for (IView<IEntity> view : views) … The wildcard bound isn't adding any information that either the compiler or anyone reading the code can use.

Comment: Also, consider moving the <T extends IEntity<T>> constraint into the declarations of IView and IKey instead of repeating them in every using method. Also, what is the reason behind render() *not* calling getKey().getEntity() automatically? (Or behind there not being a method that does that.)

Comment: My metarecommendation would be: do not use complicated generics for the sake of using complicated generics. Use them, first and foremost, to help clients of an API use it correctly. It is perfectly permissible to have three lines of internal code use raw types if you know it's correct anyway – if API clients need to do the same thing often, encapsulate this in another function and expose *that* in the API.

Comment: I think your second solution has the same issues as your first. I've given a second answer, hope it helps.

Comment: 1) `render()` does not call `getKey()` because I don't want to require it to. I want to provide the <T>-entity. 2) I removed a lot generics and bounds in my new code. Got it working (compiler not complaining anymore) though I'm not completely sure if it's safe at runtime; For an example, see http://pastie.org/private/5ivelupkeua3tv9wxic4q